# Why my collection is not always sorted?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, meteor

I have a collection that is not always sorted.

To subscribe and sort it I made:

```
infosCtn() {
        return InfosContainers.find({}, {sort: {nameContainer: 1}});
}
```

Then the thing is when I go to the app the collection is sorted:
[image]

so I stop a container and it put it at the bottom (it's not really a problem since I stopped it maybe it's not that bad to have running on top and stopped at bottom):
[image]

and I start it again but it stay on the bottom:
[image]

What is making this behaviour ? Why the order is not the same ?

As asked there is the InfosContainers:
[image]
and the return is:

```
LocalCollection.Cursor {collection: LocalCollection, sorter: M…o.Sorter, matcher: M…o.Matcher, _selectorId: undefined, skip: undefined…}collection: LocalCollectionfields: undefinedlimit: undefinedmatcher: Minimongo.Matcherreactive: trueskip: undefinedsorter: Minimongo.Sorter_projectionFn: function (obj)_selectorId: undefined_transform: null__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Can you show your `InfosContainers` and your `find()` functions? Those images you posted aren't super helpful.

Comment: @radiovisual so you mean to show the content of the find ?

Comment: What do you mean "I stopped a container and put it at the bottom"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you can imagine it as "I have a list of products and I click on >this product is no longer available< then I click on >this product is available<"

Comment: It looks like the nameContainer value used to be "_/allconnect_mongo_1_", then it was changed to "_allconnect_mongo_1_" (without the leading slash). Can you double-check?

Comment: @VinceBowdren you are the real hero ! It's that ! put an answer so I can mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the sorting is working correctly, but your data has changed, so now the documents come out in a different order.

The *nameContainer* value used to be */allconnect_mongo_1*, then it was changed to *allconnect_mongo_1* (without the leading slash).